# Override Application Package name for Here Maps initialization for different Android build types

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, here-api

I am using different build types and flavors for testing my app. In my `buildTypes` in the `debug` object I apply the `applicationIdSuffix` with *`.debug`* so I can have both the released and debug versions of my app to test on a device.

However, HereMaps doesn't like the appended `.debug` when initializing the map engine. Since that isn't the package name registered with HereMaps. I've looked in the Credentials portion of the HereMaps site and I haven't seen anywhere that I can add a sandbox or some other secondary credential for testing purposes.

Is there a way to pass override what package name the HereMaps engine is looking for? Or is there some other credentials I can generate to test with?

I don't like just switching to my "release" build just to test mapping.

Answer (score 0):

Credentials are unique to your account and your application's package namespace. Avoid reusing credentials across multiple applications.

your HERE SDK AAR matches the name in your application's build Gradle file. Note: This is only needed, if you reference the version explicitly.

You can create two sets of keys if you have a freemium account, that way you can have one application for testing and one production ready